# "No such table" error in SQLite Android using SQLIteOpenHelper

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created a DBHandler class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. I am getting an error with the category table:

`E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: CATEGORY in "INSERT INTO CATEGORY(Locked,Name,Level,BoolQuestions) VALUES (?,?,?,?)" E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: CATEGORY in "SELECT * FROM CATEGORY WHERE Name = ?"`

onCreate is

```
  db.beginTransaction();
    try {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME + "(" + CATEGORY_COL_NAME_NAME + " Text PRIMARY KEY," + CATEGORY_COL_LEVEL_NAME + " INT," + CATEGORY_COL_LOCKED_NAME + " INT," + CATEGORY_COL_BOOLQ_NAME + " INT);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ROUND_NAME + "(" + ROUND_COL_ID_NAME + " INT PRIMARY KEY," + ROUND_COL_POINTS_NAME + " INT," + ROUND_COL_TOTQ_NAME + " INT," + ROUND_COL_CORRECT_NAME + " INT," + ROUND_COL_CATEGORY_NAME + " Text,"
                + "FOREIGN KEY(" + ROUND_COL_CATEGORY_NAME + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME + "(" + CATEGORY_COL_NAME_NAME + "));");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BOOLQUESTION_NAME + "(" + BOOLQUESTION_COL_ID_NAME + " INT PRIMARY KEY," + BOOLQUESTION_COL_TEXTSE_NAME + " Text," + BOOLQUESTION_COL_TEXTEN_NAME + " Text," + BOOLQUESTION_COL_CORRANSWER_NAME + " INT," + ROUND_COL_CATEGORY_NAME + " Text,"
                + "FOREIGN KEY(" + BOOLQUESTION_COL_CATEGORY_NAME + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME + "(" + CATEGORY_COL_NAME_NAME + "));");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

Where

```
    //Tables and columns
private final String TABLE_ROUND_NAME = "ROUND";
private final String ROUND_COL_ID_NAME = "ID";
private final String ROUND_COL_POINTS_NAME = "Points";
private final String ROUND_COL_TOTQ_NAME = "TotalQuestions";
private final String ROUND_COL_CORRECT_NAME = "CorrectAnswers";
private final String ROUND_COL_CATEGORY_NAME = "Category";

private final String TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME = "CATEGORY";
private final String CATEGORY_COL_NAME_NAME = "Name";
private final String CATEGORY_COL_LEVEL_NAME = "Level";
private final String CATEGORY_COL_LOCKED_NAME = "Locked";
private final String CATEGORY_COL_BOOLQ_NAME = "BoolQuestions";

private final String TABLE_BOOLQUESTION_NAME = "BOOLQUESTION";
private final String BOOLQUESTION_COL_ID_NAME = "ID";
private final String BOOLQUESTION_COL_TEXTSE_NAME = "Text_SE";
private final String BOOLQUESTION_COL_TEXTEN_NAME = "Text_EN";
private final String BOOLQUESTION_COL_CORRANSWER_NAME = "CorrectAnswer";
private final String BOOLQUESTION_COL_CATEGORY_NAME = "Category";

//Category name contents
private final String CATEGORY_ROW_ADDSUBTRACT_NAME = "ADD_SUBTRACT";
```

onUpgrade is

```
   @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BOOLQUESTION_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ROUND_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME);
            onCreate(db);

}
```

And the only calls to the database are from MainActivity's onCreate:

```
DBHandler.getInstance(this).insertCategory(Category.add_subtract,0,false,false);
```

and from onViewCreated in a fragment:

```
        categoryModelArrayList.add(DBHandler.getInstance(view.getContext()).getCategoryModel(Category.add_subtract));
```

Why isn't the CATEGORY table being created?

The retrieve and insert methods look like this:

```
    public CategoryModel getCategoryModel(Category category) {

    CategoryModel cModel = new CategoryModel();
    String categoryName = categoryENumToString(category);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT *" + " FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME + " WHERE " + CATEGORY_COL_NAME_NAME + " = ?", new String[] {categoryName});
        System.out.println(category + " Count: " + cursor.getCount());
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            cModel.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            cModel.setMedal(cursor.getInt(1));
            if(cursor.getInt(2) == 1) {
                cModel.setLocked(true);
            } else {
                cModel.setLocked(false);
            }
            if(cursor.getInt(3) == 1) {
                cModel.setBoolQuestions(true);
            } else {
                cModel.setBoolQuestions(false);
            }
        }
        return cModel;
    }finally {
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}

public void insertCategory(Category category, int level, boolean locked, boolean boolQ) {

    String sCategory;
    int iLocked;
    int iBoolQ;

    sCategory = categoryENumToString(category);

    if(locked)
        iLocked=1;
    else
        iLocked=0;

    if(boolQ)
        iBoolQ=1;
    else
        iBoolQ=0;

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CATEGORY_COL_NAME_NAME, sCategory);
        values.put(CATEGORY_COL_LEVEL_NAME, level);
        values.put(CATEGORY_COL_LOCKED_NAME, iLocked);
        values.put(CATEGORY_COL_BOOLQ_NAME, iBoolQ);

        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME, null, values);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using Room-ORM instead of SQLite directly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).